# Homology of Subspace vs. Homology of Ambient Space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ , so that the manifold has non-trivial $k-th$ homology for some $n \geq k\geq 0$ . How do we identify the fact that while there is a non-trivial cycle in $M$ (i.e.,a cycle  $C$that does not bound), that $C$ is not a non-trivial cycle in $\mathbb R^n$ itself (since $\mathbb R^n$ has trivial homology , this obviously  cannot happen). I am thinking of $H^n(S^n; \mathbb Z )=\mathbb Z$, but also of other cases. How do we allow for this condition in general where there is a subspace $S$ embedded in $X$ where $S$ is, e.g., orientable, while $S$ is not, say for even-dimensional projective spaces embedded in odd-dimensional projective spaces)? 
Do we just declare the non-bounding cycle C , as a non-bounding cycle in the subspace S to be a bounding cycle in the ambient space? And, do we declare the cycle that "witnesses" non-orientability in the subspace to not be a cycle in the ambient space?

Comment: You are using $n$ for two different things in your first sentence. It is much clearer if you do not do that.

Comment: Aparte from that: are you asking «how can a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ have non trivial homology in positive degrees while $\mathbb R^n$ does not?»

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: basically, yes.

Comment: Have you looked at the case of the circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$? All the disks bounded by the circle have to contain points that are not in the circle.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question to be clearer then :-)

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: @anomaly: who are you replying to?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Does this imply that these are not cycles in the ambient space? I mean that $S^1$ is not considered a cycle in $\mathbb R^2$ or that $S^1$ does not bound any subspace in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @Guest No they are still cycles. They're also boundaries in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not in $S^1$, that's what I mean.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: But let's consider a case of a non-trivial cycle in an embedded manifold (say in $\mathbb R^n$ ) , since in $\mathbb R^n$ every cycle bounds. How would a non-trivial cycle in an embedded $M$ become trivial as a cycle in the ambient space?

Comment: @Guest: That was directed to you. Why would you expect a space embedded in (say) a contractible space to be itself contractible?

Comment: @anomaly: I am trying to reconcile the fact that a non-trivial cycle in a subspace cannot be non-trivial in the ambient space, or a non-orientable subspace has a cycle that does not witness non-orientability in the larger space. What is the theory behind this?

Comment: @Guest: Again, I'm not sure why you would expect anything different. An inclusion $i:X \to Y$ induces a map $i_*:H_*(X) \to H_*(Y)$, but there's no reason why it should be injective or surjective in general. (Compare the general case to that of, say, a deformation retract.)

Comment: @anomaly: O.K, I did not know that it was an issue of using the inclusion map, that clears it, thanks.